# Local variable referenced before assignment in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have very little experience with Python and I am just trying to make a function that gets the Greatest Common Divisor given an integer (number of elements in the list) and a list that comprises positive integers

```
def generalGCD(num, arr):
    if (num==2):
        gcd(arr[0],arr[1])
    else:
        gcd(arr[0],generalGCD(num-1, arr[1::]))
    def gcd(a, b) :
        if (b == 0):
            return a
        else:
            return gcd(b, a % b)
```

I am getting the following error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'gcd' referenced before assignment`

Can someone please tell why I am getting this error?
Thanks

**EDIT:
My code is wrong, this is the correct way of doing it:**

```
def generalGCD(arr): 
  def gcd(a, b):
    if (b == 0):
      return a
    else:
      return gcd(b, a % b)

  if (len(arr)>2):
    return generalGCD([gcd(arr[0],arr[1])] + arr[2::])
  else: return gcd(arr[0], arr[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `gcd` definition above its use. I also took the liberty of adding return statements, otherwise `generalGCD` would always return `None`.

```
def generalGCD(num, arr):
    def gcd(a, b) :
        if (b == 0):
            return a
        else:
            return gcd(b, a % b)
    if (num==2):
        return gcd(arr[0],arr[1])
    else:
        return gcd(arr[0],generalGCD(num-1, arr[1::]))
```